# No puedo hacer compilar "Using variable 'cg' before assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

necesito ayuda apenas se programación y no entiendo mucho esto.
el código debe permitir la digitación continua de valores hasta cuando se digita una número negativo

```
    a = input()
while a<10:
    cg = cg+1
    if (a%5)==0:
            c5 = c5+1
    if (a%3)==0:
            c3 = c3+1
    if (a%15)==0:
            c15 = c15+1
    a = float(input())
print(cg," entraron")
print(c15," son multiplos de 15")
print(c5," son multiplos solo de 5")
print(c3,"son multiplos solo de 3")
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero,

```
a = input()
```

deja en a un string de caracteres, no un valor entero. Debes usar en cambio:

```
a = int(input())
```

para convertir dicho string en un valor entero.

Las variables hay que inicializarlas antes de usarlas, o si no aparece el mensaje de error que señalas.

Por ejemplo, en la expresión

```
cg = cg + 1
```

dices que el nuevo valor de cg se obtiene sumando 1 al valor actual. La cuestión es entonces, ¿con que valor parte cg? No está dicho en el código. Eso es lo que alega el interprete.

Pasa lo mismo con los restantes contadores. Entonces, hay que inicializarlos asignándoles algún valor antes de comenzar.

```
 cg = c5  = c3 = c15 = 0
```

Luego, la condición es que el valor sea menor que cero, o sea que hay que seguir iterando mientras sea positivo.

```
while a >= 0:
```

Entonces, la versión final sería:

```
a = int(input())
cg = c5  = c3 = c15 = 0
while a >= 0:
    cg = cg+1
    if a % 5 == 0:
        c5 = c5 + 1
    if a % 3 == 0:
        c3 = c3 + 1
    if a % 15 == 0:
        c15 = c15 + 1
    a = int(input())

print(cg," entraron")
print(c15," son multiplos de 15")
print(c5," son multiplos solo de 5")
print(c3,"son multiplos solo de 3")
```

Observaciones

Si ingresas el valor 15, cuenta como múltiplo de 3, 5 y 15. Tienes que ajustar los calculos (o las leyendas).

Answer (score 1):

a = input()

cg = 0 //Debes asignarle un valor antes de utilizarla con la expresion +